# Driving 3 V relay with ESP32 and transistor

Tags: microcontroller, relay, esp32

I am trying to drive a [3 V relay](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g6rl.pdf) with an ESP32 by using a [BCP56](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BCP56_BCX56_BC56PA.pdf) transistor, based on several guides that I have found online.

Below is my design for this purpose, but it does not trigger the relay. **VDD** is 3.3 V, **REL** is ESP32 output PIN.

[image: MCU driving relay with NPN transistor BCP56]

I could really use hint what is wrong with this approach.

Comment: Probably need more base current than you are allowing for. It appears that the relay requires about 75 mA. So you probably want a base current of around 5 mA or better. That current would drop 5 V across R2 and I suspect you don't have enough voltage to support 6V or so at the REL input. The goal is then to reduce the value of R2 so that it drops the difference between about 0.8 VBE at Q1 and whatever voltage you supply at REL from the ESP32 (I don't know for sure, but would guess 3 V to 3.3 V.) Maybe a 470 Ohm resistor?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In the end I discovered a poor solder joint between ESP chip and PCB. I can confirm that it works with both 1K and suggested 470 Ohm. I feel stupid for not checking more throughly. When I was doing continuity test it was working, as it seems that chip was almost touching PCB and small press from probe was enough to make contact with the PCB and lead me to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: Perhaps you could write up an answer to your own question and then select it. It's allowed. And there isn't a better person to answer your question, now!

Comment: How do you feed the relay? Separate power?

Comment: I am using the same power rail for the MCU and relay. My input is actually 24 V DC and there is a DC-DC converter providing 3.3 V with a fairly big capacitor on the output.

Answer (score 1):

So just to answer my own question, it was a problem with the solder joint on the PCB and not the design itself.

I can confirm that the transistor triggers the relay correctly with 1K resistor as well as with suggested lower value or 470 Ohm.